# Ошибка "Out of memory: Java heap space. Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle..."

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

Ошибка

> ```
>  Out of memory: Java heap space. Please assign more memory to Gradle in
>  the project's gradle.properties file. For example, the following line,
>  in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to
>  1,024 MB: <em>org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m</em>
>    Read Gradle's configuration guide -> https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:configuring_jvm_memory
>  Read about Java's heap size -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html
> ```

Я пробовал и увеличивать значение в строке:

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxHeapSize\= -Xmx512m

Так же в файле **studio.exe.vmoptions** изменил значения:

> -Xms512m
>   -Xmx1024m

Но ничего не помогло.

Внимание вопрос как исправить это, иначе уже скоро у меня начнЁтся нервный тик.

[Upd -> Нервный тик всЁ-таки начался но вот проблему я решил обновлением grabl'a](http://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

Upd -> не помогло.

Comment: странный знак "\" в параметрах. попробуйте выделить больше чем 512, 2Gb например

Comment: а что вы пытаетесь сделать, когда получаете эту ошибку? варианты решения этих проблем для андроида есть на стеке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547100/error-in-build-gradle-in-android-studio

Comment: По этому посту я и пытался исправить эту ошибку, получаю её когда пытаюсь запустить свой проект на эмуляторе или телефоне.

Comment: Вообще странная какая-то ошибка, то она есть то её нету.

Comment: Возможно у вас просто тяжёлая картинка вот и падает. Раскажите что может привести к ошибке. Сколько бы вы не повышали доступную память она всё равно конечна, т.о. проблему надо решать иначе.

Comment: Эта строка неправильная: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxHeapSize\= -Xmx512m` - не указано значение для `MaxHeapSize`. Попробуйте без него (как рекомендовано в ошибке): `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m` или оформите полноценно `org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=1024m -Xmx1024m`. Да, если вдруг у вас Win32, то больше чем 768m выделить одному процессу нельзя.

Comment: Я изменил строку на `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024` вроде пока ошибок не было, но они появлялись и с ней до сегодняшнего дня.